# Extract "with" block in Kotlin Code with IntelliJ

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

Assuming `data` is a normal Kotlin data class, I want to surround a block with a `with` construct, so that

```
  myFun(data.start, data.end, data.name)
```

becomes

```
  with(data) { myFun(start, end, name) }
```

Could that be done with an IntelliJ refactoring (ideally with a keyboard shortcut). I couldn't find any suitable option in IntelliJ 2022.3

Comment: I think the correct answer to this question is the single word "No."

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of such a refactoring, or any way to do this in one step.

However, I would usually just extract a function from it:

1. extract a function from this expression with `Ctrl + Alt + M`
2. (sometimes) if `data` was captured in the function instead of automatically passed as param, I would make it a param by using `Ctrl + Alt + P` on it. This might happen if `data` is a property that's available wherever your new function ends up.
3. turn the param into a receiver by using `Alt + Enter` on the `data` param declaration and selecting the quick action `Convert parameter to receiver`

Now you should have:

```kotlin
data.myFun2() // call site

fun TypeOfData.myFun2() = myFun(start, end, name)
```

Then you can leave things this way (I personally like it like that), but if you want your end result to look like in your question, you can do a couple more steps:

1. manually change `data.myFun2()` to `with(data) { myFun2() }` (simpler because you have only one occurrence to change now)
2. inline the call to `myFun2()` with `Ctrl + Alt + N`

But the whole sequence might feel overkill if you want to go to this result.

Comment: Thanks for your approach, but I don't want to pull `myFun` into the data class in my case, cause it's doing I/O.

Comment: @StefanHaberl it's an extension, it's not pulling it into the data class